# Getting users under roles within governor limits

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a hierarchy of roles and its subroles in a map.
I want to fetch all users under each role and have all the users under that user.

For example

Role : director Marketing

SubRole : RM East

SubRole : RM West

Subrole : RM North

Subrole : RM South

i have this as   `Map<id, set<id>>`

If Phil is the Director Marketing
i want all the users reporting to Phil and under those users also have users reporting to RM. There could be multiple users under each role i would need help to find a way to capture these in some collection.

```
Phil - Director Marketing
      Kevin - RM South   
           Clara - TM
           Joe   - TM
      Robin - RM North
           Rita  - TM
           John  - TM
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a helper class to solve this exact problem.

```
public with sharing class GroupsHelper {
    private static final String userPrefix = User.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();

    public Map<Id, Set<Id>> roleUsers { get; private set; }
    public Map<Id, Set<Id>> roleSubordinateUsers { get; private set; }
    public Map<Id, Set<Id>> groupsUsers { get; private set; }
    public Map<Id, Set<Id>> usersGroups { get; private set; }
    public Map<Id, Set<Id>> usersQueues { get; private set; }

    public GroupsHelper() {
        this.roleUsers = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        this.roleSubordinateUsers = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        this.groupsUsers = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        this.usersGroups = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        this.usersQueues = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
        refresh(true, true);
    }

    public void refresh(Boolean refreshRoles, Boolean refreshGroups) {
        if(refreshRoles) {
            refreshRoles();
        }
        if(refreshGroups) {
            refreshGroups();
        }
    }

    public void refreshRoles() {
        roleUsers.clear();
        roleSubordinateUsers.clear();
        //Populate a Map with the role Id and all the users
        Map<Id, UserRole> roles = new Map<Id, UserRole>([
            SELECT
                Id,
                Name,
                ParentRoleId,
                (
                    SELECT
                        Id,
                        Name
                    FROM
                        Users
                )
            FROM
                UserRole]);
        Set<Id> userIds;
        Id subordinateId;
        for(UserRole role : roles.values()) {
            //Add the User Ids of the current role
            roleUsers.put(role.Id, (new Map<Id, User>(role.Users)).keySet());
            //Loop throuh and populate the role and subordinate Map
            subordinateId = null;
            while(role != null) {
                if(!roleSubordinateUsers.containsKey(role.Id)) {
                    roleSubordinateUsers.put(role.Id, new Set<Id>());
                }
                userIds = roleSubordinateUsers.get(role.Id);
                if(roleSubordinateUsers.containsKey(subordinateId)) {
                    userIds.addAll(roleSubordinateUsers.get(subordinateId));
                }
                for(User user : role.Users) {
                    userIds.add(user.Id);
                }
                subordinateId = role.Id;
                role = roles.get(role.ParentRoleId);
            }
        }
    }

    public void refreshGroups() {
        groupsUsers.clear();
        usersGroups.clear();
        Map<Id, Group> groups = new Map<Id, Group>([
            SELECT
                Id,
                Name,
                Type,
                        RelatedId,
                (
                    SELECT
                        UserOrGroupId
                    FROM
                        GroupMembers
                ),
                (
                    SELECT
                        Id,
                        SobjectType
                    FROM
                        QueueSobjects
                )
            FROM
                Group]);

        List<Id> stack;
        Set<Id> userIds, queueIds;
        Group groop;
        for(Id groupId : groups.keySet()) {
            stack = new List<Id> { groupId };
            userIds = new Set<Id>();
            do {
                groop = groups.get(stack.remove(0));
                //This is extra cautious, it should not be possible to get a null value
                if(groop != null) {
                    if(groop.RelatedId != null) {
                        if(groop.Type == 'Role') {
                            userIds.addAll(roleUsers.get(groop.RelatedId));
                        } else if(groop.Type == 'RoleAndSubordinates') {
                            userIds.addAll(roleSubordinateUsers.get(groop.RelatedId));
                        }
                    } else {
                        for(GroupMember member : groop.GroupMembers) {
                            if(isPrefix(member.UserOrGroupId, userPrefix)) {
                                userIds.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
                            } else {
                                //When the Id is not a user Id it is reliably a group Id, that we can add to the stack for processing
                                stack.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while(!stack.isEmpty());
            if(userIds.size() > 0) {
                groupsUsers.put(groupId, userIds);
                for(Id userId : userIds) {
                    if(!usersGroups.containsKey(userId)) {
                        usersGroups.put(userId, new Set<Id>());
                    }
                    usersGroups.get(userId).add(groupId);
                }
            }
        }
        for(Id userId : usersGroups.keySet()) {
            if(!usersQueues.containsKey(userId)) {
                usersQueues.put(userId, new Set<Id>());
            }
            for(Id groupId : usersGroups.get(userId)) {
                groop = groups.get(groupId);
                if(groop.Type == 'Queue' && groop.QueueSobjects.size() > 0) {
                    usersQueues.get(userId).addAll((new Map<Id, QueueSobject>(groop.QueueSobjects)).keySet());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Boolean isPrefix(Id sfdcId, String prefix) {
        if(sfdcId == null || prefix == null || prefix.length() != 3) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(sfdcId).startsWith(prefix);
        }
    }

    private static testMethod void testGroupsHelper() {
        GroupsHelper helper = new GroupsHelper();

        Integer rolesCount = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole].size();
        System.assertEquals(rolesCount, helper.roleUsers.size());
        System.assertEquals(rolesCount, helper.roleSubordinateUsers.size());

        if(helper.usersQueues.size() > 0) {
        Integer queueCount = [SELECT Id FROM QueueSobject].size();
            Id userId = new List<Id>(helper.usersQueues.keySet())[0];
            System.assertEquals(queueCount, helper.usersQueues.get(userId).size());
        }

        //Can't test the size of the groups and users Maps because they only
        //contain a key if there are child values to add.
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also mention the usage:
    GroupsHelper helper = new GroupsHelper();
    helper.roleSubordinateUsers.get(roleId) //returns all users in role

Comment: thanks a ton.. I have a question though.. would this code return me just the users under that role or all users including subroles?

Comment: The issue that i face is not getting all the users but to have those in a hierarchy. i need to somehow identify that Kevin is under Phil, and joe and clara are under Kevin

Comment: i get a incorrect signature at line 113 if(PrefixesHelper.isPrefix(member.UserOrGroupId, userPrefix)) {

Comment: @prady to answer your first question. The roleUsers Map returns only the users who are in the role. The roleSubordinateUsers Map returns all the users in the role and all subordinate roles.

Comment: I hope this more detailed example explains your problem (sorry about the terrible formatting):

`GroupsHelper helper = new GroupsHelper();` 
`//This list will contain phil` 
`List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :helper.roleUsers.get(kevin.UserRoleId)];` 
`User phil = users[0];`
`//This list will contain joe and clara`
`users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :helper.roleUsers.get(phil.UserRoleId)];`
`//This list will contain phil, joe and clara`
`users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :helper.roleSubordinateUsers.get(phil.UserRoleId)];`